# Возможно ли вступление бота в групповой чат по пригласительной ссылке?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Возможно ли реализовать автоматическое вступление телеграмм бота в чат по пригласительной ссылке?
Если да, то как?
заранее благодарен.
Бот на python.

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.join_chat_by_link(invite_link)
```

Comment: нет такого атрибута у бота пишет

Comment: можно пожалуйста полный код и полное сообщение ошибки?